# R: Rvest Webscraping 4Chan Catalog

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a 4chan for political research. I am interested in the 4chan catalog and the following nodes "#threads div.teaser > b". `html_nodes()` works fine however does not have a default value for when a particular `<b> TITLE </b>` is absent - it just pulls what it can find into a vector.

And this is important because I need to know when a particular `div.teaser` has no title. I am really stuck here, see code below:

```
library(googlesheets)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

#Get web driver up
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port= 4837L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$open() 
remDr$navigate("https://boards.4channel.org/pol/catalog")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))

# fetch the html code
remDr$refresh()
soup <- remDr$getPageSource()
soup <- xml2::read_html(soup[[1]])

#obtain titles (not working)
soup %>%  
  if_else(is.null(html_nodes("#threads div.teaser > b")), 0,1)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a `xml_document/xml_node` object.
```

However, I thought is.null() would do just that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution could be `TryCatch` function.

Below a possible solution:

```
    library(googlesheets)
    library(RSelenium)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rvest)
    library(xml2)
    
    #Get web driver up
    rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port= 4837L)
    remDr <- rD[["client"]]
    remDr$open() 
    remDr$navigate("https://boards.4channel.org/pol/catalog")
    webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
    
    # fetch the html code
    remDr$refresh()
    soup <- remDr$getPageSource()
    soup <- xml2::read_html(soup[[1]])
    
    #obtain titles (not working)

    x<-soup %>%  tryCatch( expr = { html_nodes("#threads div.teaser > b")}, 
    error = function(e){1})
    print(x)
    [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately, this expression seems to evaluate the function as a whole ie, is there any data in the vector at all? and returns 1 because it does contain some data.

Comment: Trycatch returns 1 if the html_nodes makes error. 
The goal of this trycatch is to manage the error of the html_nodes.

Comment: for example: if html_node works, x will have the value of the html_nodes, in other cases you will have 1

Comment: ok, so how would I go about passing a 'null' value when an element is blank, and then the element value when it is present?

Comment: In this case trycatch manages just the error. If the node is null does't make the error and your x it will be NULL, if the node doesn't exsist you have  the error and you will have the 1 as results.